# Has a totally eclipsed Sun been photographed from low Earth orbit?

Tags: low-earth-orbit, photography, solar-eclipse, corona

I'm hoping to get a sense of how much of the corona can be seen during an eclipse of the sun from outside of Earth's atmosphere.

Have any photographs been taken in the visible part of the spectrum, from low earth orbit, of a total eclipse of the sun?

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.space.com/amp/37861-solar-eclipse-photos-from-space-by-astronauts.html

Comment: Nevermind the sun, how about a total eclipse of the heart?

Comment: @Lithobrake Have you found a photo of that, and does it reveal the size of the corona?

Comment: @Bob516 Probably just the size of the coronary. That said, I can't help but think orbital solar telescopes would probably be better at mechanically shading the solar disc for coronal observation than waiting to pass through a Moonshadow.

Comment: This is an interesting question! I've modified the title to make sure nobody tries to make this a duplicate of questions about photographing the shadow of the eclipse (e.g. [here]()). But why do you limit this to LEO (low Earth orbit) only? Are you sure you want to exclude other Earth orbits, the Moon, other planets and deep space? I think you could replace LEO with simply "in space" or "outside Earth's atmosphere".

Comment: Also, would you like to exclude or include satellites with [coronagraphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coronagraph) which use "artificial eclipses" to photograph the Sun's corona, e.g. [SOHO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_and_Heliospheric_Observatory) and [STEREO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STEREO)?

Comment: @uhoh I specified LEO because its relevant to the novel I'm writing. I guess saying within the earth's Hill Sphere would also serve my purpose.

Comment: @Bob516 all of that would be great to add back into your question post! This is a pretty helpful and friendly site, and a good technical question like this may attract more good-will and interest in answers if users knew your reason; there are plenty of sci-fi friendly folks here. Also, many readers won't read through comments for clarifications; they should really be edited back into the original post for visibility, which also bumps your question back into the active queue.